# How to send FCM Token ID to PHP server?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The FCM Token ID has been generated and I want it to send to the PHP server and then store it in a variable. What should be the approach?

```
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    }
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

$token = $_POST["tokenid"];
echo ($token);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store you FCM-Id in Preference and then pass this FCM-Id to backend pass it as a parametr using API calling. here below i'm get FCM-Id and pas to PHP using API.

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    Context context;

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        AppPreference.setStringPref(context, AppPreference.PREF_SIGNUP_FCM_ID, AppPreference.PREF_KEY.PREF_KEY_FCM_ID,
                refreshedToken);
        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    // [END refresh_token]


    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     * <p>
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.


        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String device_id = Common.getDeviceId(this);
        params.put(FCM_TOKEN, token);
        params.put(DEVICEID, device_id);
        params.put(DEVICE_TYPE, device_type);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(FCM_TOKEN_URL, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            parseJsonPersonalDetail(response);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                            int statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;

                            Log.d("testerror", "" + statusCode + " " + response.data);
                        }
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (TV; rv:44.0) Gecko/44.0 Firefox/44.0");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        Common.setVolleyConnectionTimeout(request);
        ApplicationClass.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);

    }


    /**
     * <b>Description</b> - Get back response for calling  callUserDetailSave API
     *
     * @param jsonObject - Pass API response
     */
    private void parseJsonPersonalDetail(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            Log.i("get response", "get response" + jsonObject);
            if (jsonObject.toString().contains(Constant.JSON_KEY.MSG)) {
                String message = jsonObject.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.MSG);
                String status = jsonObject.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.CODE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here first i'm get FCM id then call API method  `sendRegistrationToServer` and pass token in API as a paramter so back-end developer get this token from API parameter.

Here i'm pass three parameters

- params.put(FCM_TOKEN, token);
- params.put(DEVICEID, device_id);
- params.put(DEVICE_TYPE, device_type);

`device_id` and `device_type` pass because it's my requirment.

> Add dependency in app level gradle file for calling Volley API call :
>
> `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'`

Checkout i'm created Demo for you: [Demo](https://github.com/PranavBhatt25/DemoFCM)

Volley Libraries Example : 
[Tutorial 1](https://abhiandroid.com/programming/volley)
[Tutorial 2](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)
[Tutorial 3](https://www.journaldev.com/17198/android-volley-tutorial)

Comment: I've a php file running on localhost.The moment I run app on emulator, it generates token ID. And send the token to PHP,

Comment: So here you can create local funcion for API calling and put this URL here in abover code snippet: FCM_TOKEN_URL replace your local URL here.

Comment: Which libraries do I import for above code you wrote?

Comment: Check my updated answer import : implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0' for API call from volley library

Comment: If any issue arise then let men know.

Comment: Will let you know. Give me a day and hope you'll be available online tomorrow..

Comment: Sure , yup i'll be here anytime let me know (y)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207234/discussion-between-cricket-fan-and-insanecat).

Comment: Happy to help you :) @Cricket_Fan