# How can I do to send FCM token to my php server

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have exactly the same question as [How to send FCM Token ID to PHP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054798/how-to-send-fcm-token-id-to-php-server) but I have not enough reputation to comment there.
I spent 2 days on that, and I'm becoming crazy.
I have tried tons of solutions, never getting the results.
All what I find is too complicated for my beginner level (or my English level), or is deprecated.

I'd like to get the most simple way to POST Token and Device_ID (I know how to get both) to my server. Never mind if it is JSON, GET or POST method, or anything else.
Just a simple way to do it.
I don't want any UI or anything else like that. A an automatic way to send the FCM token when generated.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        String id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        sendRegistrationToServer(token, id);
    }
}
```

I just need sendRegistrationToServer()

Thanks a lot by advance.

**EDIT**
I finaly got it working with :
DeviceService.java

```
public interface DeviceService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("fcm_token_register.php")
    Call<String> insertToken(@Field("token") String token, @Field("id") String id);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://*myserver*/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

Calling it by :

```
DeviceService service = DeviceService.retrofit.create(DeviceService.class);
Call<String> call = service.insertToken(token,id);
call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OK : "+response.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error : "+t.toString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) to request to PHP server.

```kotlin
interface YourService {

    @POST("your endpoint")
    fun registerFcmToken(@Body body: RegistrationBody): Call<Response>
}
...
data class RegistrationBody(val token: String, val deviceId: String)
```

Comment: I already tried with retrofit. I understood that could be the solution, but I'm not able to do it, and your example seem not to be detailled enough for me. sorry.

Comment: What's the difficulty exactly? Do you need a way how to make a request with retrofit?

Comment: Yes. (google translate because of my english) I find a lot of very cumbersome solutions, and which seem to me oversized compared to my needs, and in addition, I am unable to implement them within the framework of my need. I can't figure out what I should create as a class, as an interface, and what to call it all.